# Why is the write to non-volatile visible to the main-thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Imagine the following program.

```java
class Main {


    static class Whatever {
        int x = 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Whatever whatever = new Whatever();

        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            whatever.x = 1;
        });
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        System.out.println(whatever.x);
    }
}
```

The main-thread has cached `whatever` and `x` is set to `0`. The other thread starts, caches `whatever` and sets the cached `x` to `1`.

The output is

```
1
```

so the main-thread has seen the write. Why is that?

Why was the write done to the shared cache and why has the main-thread invalidated its cache to read from the shared cache? Why don't I need `volatile` here?

Comment: Not having a *happens-before* doesn't guarantee that you _won't_ see the change. (In this case, you have one, but it's always possible for unsynchronized threads to be updated by accident.)

Comment: @akuzminykh Note that there aren't really caches that behave this way on modern hardware. We use them as an abstraction to understand the rules of the language. Java could, in theory, be implemented on hardware that has such caches, and imagining that your hardware is like that helps you to more easily understand why `volatile` and synchronization is needed rather than trying to understand the absurd complexity of modern hardware and modern compiler optimizations. This is why code that gets synchronization wrong tends to fail in very unpredictable ways or not at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the main thread joining on it. See
17.4.5 in the JLS:

> All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.

Btw it is true that not having a happens-before doesn’t necessarily mean something won’t be visible.